# How to store text corresponding to the number(value) in on-change drop-down?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, onchange

I am using on-change drop-down with 4 levels. It works well and display the Name(Text) correctly. But when I store it to mysql database it stores the value number not the text. How do I store the text corresponding to the value(Number)

The HTML Code is

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-lg-3"><select class="form-control" onchange="javascript:Loaddistrict();" id="s_zone" name="s_zone"><option value="">Select Zone</option>
      <option value="1">Chennai</option>
      <option value="2">Coimbatore</option>
      <option value="3">Cuddalore</option>
      <option value="4">Madurai</option>
      <option value="5">Salem</option>
      <option value="6">Tanjore</option>
      <option value="7">Thirunelveli</option>
      <option value="8">Trichy</option>
      <option value="9">Vellore</option></select></div>

  <div id="district" class="col-lg-3"><select class="form-control" onchange="javascript:Loadsro();" id="s_district" name="s_district"><option value="">Select District</option></select></div>

  <div class="col-lg-3" id="sro"><select class="form-control" onchange="javascript:Loadvillage();" id="s_sro" name="s_sro"><option value="">Select SRO</option></select></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" id="village"><select class="form-control" id="s_village" name="s_village"><option value="">Select Village</option></select></div>
</div>
```

Java script is

```js
 

    <script type="text/javascript"  language="JavaScript">

var zonecode
var distcode
var srocode

zonecode=0
distcode=0
srocode=0

function loadDistrict(id)
{
 zonecode = document.EC.zone.value;
 var selectid = document.EC.zone.value;
 var slist = '47~9@Arakkonam;31~6@Ariyalur;4~1@Chengalpattu;3~1@Chennai Central;2~1@Chennai North;1~1@Chennai South;40~8@Cheranmadevi;48~9@Cheyyar;14~3@Chidambaram;6~2@Coimbatore;11~3@Cuddalore;26~5@Dharmapuri;19~4@Dindugul;9~2@Erode;10~2@Gobichettipalayam;13~3@Kallakurichi;5~1@Kancheepuram;41~8@Kaniyakumari;20~4@Karaikudi;32~6@Karur;27~5@Krishnagiri;39~7@Kumbakonam;18~4@Madurai North;17~4@Madurai South;35~7@Maiyaladuthurai;42~8@Marthandam;36~7@Nagapattinam;28~5@Namakkal;8~2@Ooty;21~4@Palani;43~8@Palayankottai;37~7@Pattukkottai;22~4@Periyakulam;33~6@Pudukottai;23~4@Ramanathapuram;29~5@Salem East;30~5@Salem West;25~4@Sivagengai;46~8@Tenkasi;38~7@Thanjavur;7~2@Thiruppur;49~9@Thiruvannamalai;15~3@Tindivanam;44~8@Tirunelveli;34~6@Trichy;45~8@Tuticorin;50~9@Vellore;12~3@Villupuram;24~4@Virudhunagar;16~3@Viruthachalam;';
//alert(slist)
 var temp = slist.split(";");

 if (id =="0") 
 {
 //alert(document.EC.district.options.length)
 document.EC.district.options.length = 1;
 //alert(document.EC.Srosel.options.length)
//alert(temp);
 if (document.EC.Srosel.options.length >= 1)
 document.EC.Srosel.options.length = 1;
 // when the zone is changed change the value of the village also 

 //document.EC.Villagesel.value="";
          document.getElementById("villagesel").value="";
 //alert(selectid)
 //document.EC.VillageName.value=""
 //alert(temp);
 }
 lCount = 1;
 checkid = 0;

 for(i=0;i<temp.length-1;i++)
 {
if(temp[i].substring(temp[i].indexOf("~")+1,temp[i].indexOf("@")) == selectid)
{

if ((id > 0) && (temp[i].substring(0,temp[i].indexOf("~")) == id))
 checkid = lCount;

document.EC.district.options[lCount] = new 
Option(temp[i].substring(temp[i].indexOf("@")+1,temp[i].length),temp[i].substring(0,temp[i].indexOf("~")));    
lCount++;
}
if (id > 0)
 document.EC.district.selectedIndex = checkid;
}


removeFromList(document.getElementById("villagesel"))
}

function loadSro(id)
{
 distcode = document.EC.district.value;
 var selectid = document.EC.district.value;
 var slist = '378~33@Aalangudi;347~31@Aandimadam;232~22@Aandipatti;18~2@Aarani (Chennai North);564~48@Aarani (Cheyyar);198~19@Aathur_dindugal;245~23@Abiramam;38~4@Acchirapakkam;1~1@Adyar;2~1@Alandur;189~18@Alanganallur;535~46@Alangulam;491~43@Alwarthirunagar;461~40@Ambasamudram;17~2@Ambattur;589~50@Ambur;106~9@Ammapettai;75~7@Anamalai;129~12@Ananthapuram;28~3@AnnaNagar;379~33@Annavasal;128~12@Anniyur;62~6@Annur;93~9@Anthiyur;130~12@Aragandanallur;559~47@Arakkonam Joint I;555~47@Arakkonam Joint II;211~20@Aranthangi;180~17@Arasaradi;367~32@Aravakurichi;552~47@Arcot;354~31@Ariyalur Joint I;348~31@Ariyalur Joint II;283~26@Aroor;482~42@Arumanai;258~24@Aruppukottai;37~3@Ashok Nagar;430~37@Athiramapattinam;325~29@Attur;14~1@Avadi;158~15@Avaloorpettai;102~9@Avalpoondurai;157~15@Avarappakkam;63~6@Avinasi;332~29@Ayothyapattinam;199~19@Ayyampalayam;445~38@Ayyampettai;295~27@Bargur;100~9@Bhavani;154~14@Bhuvanagiri;233~22@Bodinaickanur;446~38@Boothalur;470~41@Boothapandi;492~43@Burkitmanagaram;221~21@Chathirapatti;181~17@Chekkanoorani;402~35@Chembanarkovil;42~4@Chengalpattu Joint I;43~4@Chengalpattu Joint II;576~49@Chengam;33~3@Chennai Central Jointt I;35~3@Chennai Central Jointt II;22~2@Chennai North Jointt I;4~1@Chennai South Joint I;5~1@Chennai South Joint II;98~9@Chenniamalai;467~40@Cheranmadevi Joint I;462~40@Cheranmadevi Joint II;577~49@Chetput;349~31@Chettikulam;571~48@Cheyyar Joint I;567~48@Cheyyar Joint II;44~4@Cheyyur;151~14@Chidambaram Joint I;143~13@Chinna salem;368~32@Chinnadarapuram;200~19@Chinnalapatti;234~22@Chinnamanur;190~18@Chokkikulam;186~17@Chozhavandan;65~6@Coimbatore Joint I;66~6@Coimbatore Joint II;88~8@Coonoor;259~24@Coonoor_virudhunagar;403~35@Courtallam;118~11@Cuddalore Joint I;119~11@Cuddalore Joint II;416~36@Mannargudi;156~14@Mannargudi_cdm;164~15@Marakkanam;294~26@Marandahalli;487~42@Marthandam Joint I;483~42@Marthandam Joint II;409~35@Mayiladurai Joint I;407~35@Mayiladuthurai Joint II;165~15@Mayilam;341~30@Mecheri;214~20@Meemisal;353~31@Meensurutti;373~32@Melakarur;540~46@Melaneelithanallur;500~43@Melapalayam;192~18@Melur;71~6@Mettupalayam;340~30@Mettur;311~28@Moganur;511~44@Moolakaraipatti;107~9@Moolanur;288~26@Morapur;250~23@Mudukolathur;466~40@Mukkoodal;486~42@Munchirai;501~43@Murapanadu;394~34@Musiri;417~36@Muthupettai;34~3@Mylapore;458~39@Nachiyarkovil;204~19@Nagalnaickenpatti;148~13@Nagalur;420~36@Nagapattinam Joint I;419~36@Nagoor;86~7@Nallur;175~16@Nallur_Vdm;313~28@Namagiripettai;314~28@Namakkal Joint I;308~28@Namakkal Joint II;116~10@Nambiyur;374~32@Nangavaram;512~44@Nanguneri;408~35@Nanilam;206~19@Natham;594~50@Natrampalli;278~25@Nayinar kovil;502~43@Nazareth;418~36@Needamangalam;16~1@Neelankarai;83~7@Negamam;124~11@Nellikuppam;558~47@nemili;205~19@Nilakkottai;596~50@Odugathur;337~30@Omalur;304~27@Oothangarai;49~5@Oothukkottai;91~8@Ooty Joint I;92~8@Ooty Joint II;437~37@Orathanadu;602~18@Othakadai;224~21@Ottanchatram;528~45@Ottapidaram;12~1@Padappai;290~26@Palacode;225~21@Palani Joint I;223~21@Palani Joint II;503~43@Palayankottai Joint I;84~7@Palladam;7~1@Pallavaram;597~50@Pallikonda;317~28@Pallipalayam;56~5@Pallipattu;477~41@Palliyadi;488~42@Palugal;15~1@Pammal;514~44@Panagudi;541~46@Panpozhi;125~11@Panruti;264~24@Panthalkudi;459~39@Papanasam;438~37@Pappanadu;291~26@Pappireddypatti;280~25@Paramakudi;315~28@Paramathi;153~14@Parangi pettai;289~26@Parur;436~37@Pattukottai Joint I;432~37@Pattukottai Joint II;542~46@Pavoorchatram;73~6@Peelamedu;179~16@Pennadam;292~26@Pennagaram;185~17@Peraiyur;411~35@Peralam;355~31@Perambalur;572~48@Peranamallur;440~37@Peravoorani;32~3@Periamet;239~22@Periyakulam Joint I;236~22@Periyakulam Joint II;69~6@Periyanayakkan Palayam;598~50@Pernampattu;57~5@Perumbakkam;253~23@Perunazhi;101~9@Perundurai;387~33@Perungalur;531~45@Perungulam;329~29@Pethanayakkanpalayam;515~44@Pettai;300~27@Pochampalli;254~23@Poghalur;85~7@Pollachi;585~49@Polur;216~20@Ponnamaravathi;25~2@Ponneri;8~1@Poonamallee;316~28@Puduchathiram;155~14@puduchattiram;530~45@Pudukottai;386~33@Pudukottai Joint I;126~11@Pudupettai;529~45@Pudur;543~46@Puliyangudi;356~31@Pullampadi;117~10@Punchaipuliyampatti;31~3@Purasaivakkam;516~44@Radhapuram;478~41@Rajackamangalam;265~24@Rajapalayam;251~23@Rajasinghamangalam;60~5@Ramakrishnarajupettai;256~23@Ramanathapuram Joint I;246~23@Ramanathapuram Joint II;252~23@Rameshvaram;318~28@Rasipuram;301~27@Rayakottai;26~2@Redhills;146~13@Rishivanthiyam;19~2@Royapuram;40~4@Salavakkam;324~29@Salem (East) Joint I;335~30@Salem West Joint I;336~30@Salem West Joint III;208~19@Sanarpatti;345~30@Sangagiri;544~46@Sankaranainarkoil;142~13@Sankarapuram;505~43@Sathankulam;113~10@Sathiyamangalam;160~15@Sathiyamangalam_tvm;266~24@Sathur;255~23@Sayalkudi;603~1@Selaiyur;21~2@Sembiam;357~31@Sendurai;209~19@Sendurai;547~46@Senkottah;319~28@Senthamangalam;152~14@Sethiyathope;267~24@Sethur;561~47@Sholingar;240~22@Sindupatti;217~20@Singampunari;67~6@Singanallur;412~35@Sirkazhi;176~16@Sirupakkam;279~25@Sivaganga Joint I;274~25@Sivaganga Joint II;97~9@Sivagiri_erode;545~46@Sivagiri_tenkasi;268~24@Sivakasi;302~27@Soolagiri;338~30@Sooramangalam;23~2@Sowcarpet;48~4@Sriperumpudur;396~34@Srirangam;506~43@Srivaikundam;269~24@Srivilliputhur;441~37@Subbramaniyapuram;80~7@Sulur;604~4@sunguvarchattram;104~9@Surampatti;546~46@Surandai;455~39@Swamimalai;6~1@T.Nagar;3~1@Tambaram;549~46@Tenkasi Joint I;537~46@Tenkasi Joint II;358~31@Tha.Pazhur;587~49@Thaanipadi;479~41@Thackalai;426~36@Thakkattur;331~29@Thalaivasal;114~10@Thalavadi;194~18@Thallakulam;53~5@Thamal;193~18@Thamaraipatti;330~29@Thammampatti;586~49@Thandarampattu;447~38@Thanjavur Joint I;375~32@Tharagampatti;339~30@Tharamangalam;413~35@Tharangampadi;397~34@Thathaiyangarpettai;573~48@Thellar;241~22@Theni;303~27@Thenkanikottai;195~18@Theppakulam;242~22@Thevaram;99~9@Thingalur;532~45@Thiruchendur;320~28@Thiruchengode;271~24@Thiruchuli;517~44@Thirukarungudi;451~38@Thirukattupalli;45~4@Thirukazhukundram;132~12@Thirukovilur;429~36@Thirukuvalai;187~17@Thirumangalam;388~33@Thirumayam;171~16@Thirumuttam;123~11@Thirunavalur;513~44@Thirunelveli Joint I;188~17@Thiruparakundram;422~36@Thirupoondi;457~39@Thiruppanandhal;218~20@Thiruppathur (Karaikudi);599~50@Thiruppathur (Vellore);46~4@Thirupporur;81~7@Thiruppur Joint I;82~7@Thiruppur Joint II;281~25@Thirupuvanam;270~24@Thiruthangal;423~36@Thiruthuraipoondi;54~5@Thiruttani;219~20@Thiruvadanai;452~38@Thiruvaiyaru;58~5@Thiruvalankadu;55~5@Thiruvallur;584~49@Thiruvannamalai Joint I;579~49@Thiruvannamalai Joint II;398~34@Thiruvarambur;424~36@Thiruvarur;489~42@Thiruvattar;131~12@Thiruvennainallur;456~39@Thiruvidaimaruthur;442~37@Thiruvonam;24~2@Thiruvottiyur;508~43@Thisaiyanvilai;170~16@Thittakudi;144~13@Thiyagadurgam;68~6@Thondamuthur;220~20@Thondi;115~10@Thookanaicken Palayam;87~7@Thottipalayam;481~41@Thovalai;173~16@Thozhuudhur;359~31@Thuraiyur;399~34@Thuvarankurichi;162~15@Tindivanam Joint I;163~15@Tindivanam Joint II;510~44@Tiurnelveli Joint II;395~34@Trichy Joint I;390~34@Trichy Joint III;30~3@Triplicane;524~45@Tuticorin - Melur;527~45@Tuticorin Joint I;520~45@Tuticorin Joint II;533~45@Udankudi;360~31@Udayarpalayam;76~7@Udumalapettai;444~37@Ullikottai;177~16@Ulundurpettai;361~31@Uppiliyapuram;400~34@Uraiyur;244~22@Usilampatti;243~22@Uthamapalayam;39~4@Uthiramerur;95~9@Uthukuli;548~46@Uthumalai;228~21@Vada madurai;145~13@Vadakkananthal;468~40@Vadakkuveeravanallur;127~11@Vadalur;147~13@Vadaponparappi;480~41@Vadaseri;74~6@Vadavalli;197~18@Vadipatti;460~39@Valankaiman;167~15@Valathi;136~12@Valavanur;362~31@Valighandapuram;453~38@Vallam;166~15@Vallam_tvm;518~44@Valliyur;574~48@Vandavasi;600~50@Vaniyampadi;168~15@Vanur;550~46@Vasudevanallur;210~19@Vathalakundu;272~24@Vathirairuppu;328~29@Vazhapadi;229~21@Veda senthur;428~36@Vedaranyam;282~24@Veerachozhan;333~29@Veerapandi;551~46@Veerasigamani;13~1@Velacheri;322~28@Velagoundampatti;377~32@Velayuthampalayam;108~9@Vellakovil;257~23@Vellipattinam;376~32@Velliyanai;595~50@Vellore Joint I;321~28@Velur;575~48@Vembakkam;305~27@Veppannapalli;365~31@Veppanthattai;178~16@Veppur;364~31@Veppur;490~42@Verkilambi;588~49@Vettavalam;469~40@Vickramasingapuram;138~12@Vikkravandi;363~31@Vikramangalam;534~45@Vilathikulam;36~3@Villivakkam;133~12@Villupuram Joint I;134~12@Villupuram Joint II;389~33@Viralimalai;263~24@Virudhunagar Joint I;260~24@Virudhunagar Joint II;9~1@Virugambakkam;169~16@Vriddhachalam Joint I;563~47@Walaja;61~5@Walajabad;334~29@Yercaud;';
 var temp = slist.split(";");

 if (id =="0") 
 {
 if (document.EC.Srosel.options.length >= 1)
 document.EC.Srosel.options.length = 1;
 //document.EC.Villagesel.value=""
  document.getElementById("villagesel").value="";
 //document.EC.VillageName.value=""
 }
 lCount = 1;
 checkid = 0; 
 for(i=0;i<temp.length-1;i++)
 {
if(temp[i].substring(temp[i].indexOf("~")+1,temp[i].indexOf("@")) == selectid)
{
 if ((id > 0) && (temp[i].substring(0,temp[i].indexOf("~")) == id))
  checkid = lCount;
  document.EC.Srosel.options[lCount] = new 
Option(temp[i].substring(temp[i].indexOf("@")+1,temp[i].length),temp[i].substring(0,temp[i].indexOf("~")));    
lCount++;
}
if (id > 0)
 document.EC.Srosel.selectedIndex = checkid;  
}
removeFromList(document.getElementById("villagesel"))
}
function loadSro1(id)
{
 distcode = 0;
 var selectid = 0;
 var slistsro="";
 slistsro = "378~33@Aalangudi;347~31@Aandimadam;232~22@Aandipatti;18~2@Aarani (Chennai North);564~48@Aarani (Cheyyar);198~19@Aathur_dindugal;245~23@Abiramam;38~4@Acchirapakkam;1~1@Adyar;2~1@Alandur;189~18@Alanganallur;535~46@Alangulam;491~43@Alwarthirunagar;461~40@Ambasamudram;17~2@Ambattur;589~50@Ambur;106~9@Ammapettai;75~7@Anamalai;129~12@Ananthapuram;28~3@AnnaNagar;379~33@Annavasal;128~12@Anniyur;62~6@Annur;93~9@Anthiyur;130~12@Aragandanallur;559~47@Arakkonam Joint I;555~47@Arakkonam Joint II;211~20@Aranthangi;180~17@Arasaradi;367~32@Aravakurichi;552~47@Arcot;354~31@Ariyalur Joint I;348~31@Ariyalur Joint II;283~26@Aroor;482~42@Arumanai;258~24@Aruppukottai;37~3@Ashok Nagar;430~37@Athiramapattinam;325~29@Attur;14~1@Avadi;158~15@Avaloorpettai;102~9@Avalpoondurai;157~15@Avarappakkam;63~6@Avinasi;332~29@Ayothyapattinam;199~19@Ayyampalayam;445~38@Ayyampettai;295~27@Bargur;100~9@Bhavani;154~14@Bhuvanagiri;233~22@Bodinaickanur;446~38@Boothalur;470~41@Boothapandi;492~43@Burkitmanagaram;221~21@Chathirapatti;181~17@Chekkanoorani;402~35@Chembanarkovil;42~4@Chengalpattu Joint I;43~4@Chengalpattu Joint II;576~49@Chengam;33~3@Chennai Central Jointt I;35~3@Chennai Central Jointt II;22~2@Chennai North Jointt I;4~1@Chennai South Joint I;5~1@Chennai South Joint II;98~9@Chenniamalai;467~40@Cheranmadevi Joint I;462~40@Cheranmadevi Joint II;577~49@Chetput;349~31@Chettikulam;571~48@Cheyyar Joint I;567~48@Cheyyar Joint II;44~4@Cheyyur;151~14@Chidambaram Joint I;143~13@Chinna salem;368~32@Chinnadarapuram;200~19@Chinnalapatti;234~22@Chinnamanur;190~18@Chokkikulam;186~17@Chozhavandan;65~6@Coimbatore Joint I;66~6@Coimbatore Joint II;88~8@Coonoor;259~24@Coonoor_virudhunagar;403~35@Courtallam;118~11@Cuddalore Joint I;119~11@Cuddalore Joint II;327~29@Dadagapatti;212~20@Devakottai;105~9@Dharapuram;284~26@Dharmapuri (West);293~26@Dharmapuri Joint I;285~26@Dharmapuri Joint II;207~19@Dindigul Joint I;201~19@Dindugal Joint II;566~48@Dusi;343~30@Edapadi;139~13@Elavanasur;519~45@Eral;431~37@Erandampulikadu;471~41@Eranial;94~9@Erode Joint 1;307~28@Erumaipatti;366~31@Erumbulikurichi;493~43@Ettayapuram;235~22@Ezhumalai;72~6@Ganapathi;64~6@Gandhipuram;509~44@Gangaikondan;326~29@Gangavalli;161~15@Gingee;111~10@Gobichettipalayam Joint I;112~10@Gobichettipalayam Joint II;79~7@Gomangalam;89~8@Goodaloor;109~10@Goundampadi;593~50@Gudiyatham;10~1@Guduvancheri;20~2@Gummidipoondi;299~27@Hosur;536~46@Idaikkal;472~41@Idalakudi;273~25@Ilayangudi;380~33@Iluppur;342~30@Jalakandapuram;350~31@Jayakondam;590~50@Jolarpettai;392~34@K. Saathanur;580~49@Kadaladi;247~23@Kadaladi;237~22@Kadamalaikundu;494~43@Kadambur;120~11@Kadampuliyur;286~26@Kadathur;463~40@Kadayam;538~46@Kadayanallur;464~40@Kalakkadu;568~48@Kalampur;581~49@Kalasapakkam;556~47@Kalavai;275~25@Kalayarkoil;140~13@Kallakurichi Joint I;141~13@Kallakurichi Joint II;465~40@Kallidaikurichi;184~17@Kallikudi;231~21@Kallimandayam;495~43@Kalugumalai;238~22@Kambam;172~16@Kammapuram;248~23@Kamudi;52~5@Kancheepuram Joint  IV;50~5@Kancheepuram Joint I;51~5@Kancheepuram Joint II;137~12@Kandamangalam;592~50@Kaniyampadi;77~7@Kaniyur;103~9@Kankeyam;569~48@Kannamangalam;203~19@Kannivadi;383~33@Kantharvakottai;476~41@Kanyakumari Joint I;213~20@Karaikudi Joint II;215~20@Karakudi Joint I;381~33@Karambakudi;261~24@Kariapatti;287~26@Karimangalam;539~46@Karivalamvandanallur;485~42@Karungal;191~18@Karungalakudi;448~38@Karunthattankudi;370~32@Karur Joint I;369~32@Karur Joint II;591~50@Katpadi;391~34@Kattuputhur;557~47@Kaveripakkam;297~27@Kaveripattinam;521~45@Kayalpattinam;498~43@Kayathar;249~23@Keelakarai;382~33@Keelanilai;262~24@KeelaRajakularaman;433~37@Keeramangalam;226~21@Keeranur;601~50@Keezh Vazhi Thunayan Kuppam;351~31@Keezhaapazhur;523~45@Keezhur;298~27@Kelamangalam;570~48@Kilkodungalur;582~49@Kilpennathur;78~7@Kinathukadavu;29~3@Kodambakkam;405~35@Kodavasal;202~19@Kodikanal;96~9@Kodumudi;384~33@Kolathur;484~42@Kollankodu;404~35@Kollidam;497~43@Kommadikottai;27~2@Konnur;415~36@Koothanalur;90~8@Kothagiri;473~41@Kottaram;496~43@Kovilpatti;306~27@Krishnagiri Joint I;296~27@Krishnagiri Joint II;372~32@Krishnarayapuram;227~21@Kujiliamparai;474~41@Kulatchal;371~32@Kulithalai;122~11@Kullanchavadi;150~14@Kumarachi;309~28@Kumarapalayam;454~39@Kumbakonam Joint I;110~10@Kunnathur;11~1@Kunrathur;121~11@Kurinchi padi;352~31@Lalgudi;277~25@Madakkupatti;605~2@madhavaram;47~4@Madhuranthagam;70~6@Madukkarai;434~37@Madukkur;196~18@Madurai (North) Joint I;183~17@Madurai (South) Joint IV;182~17@Madurai(South) Joint I;344~30@Magudanchavadi;449~38@Makarnonbuchavadi;310~28@Mallasumudram;401~34@Manachanallur;135~12@Manalurpettai;276~25@Manamadurai;385~33@Manamelkudi;393~34@Manapparai;475~41@Manavalakurichi;59~5@Manavalanagar;583~49@Mangalam;174~16@Mangalamapettai;416~36@Mannargudi;156~14@Mannargudi_cdm;164~15@Marakkanam;294~26@Marandahalli;487~42@Marthandam Joint I;483~42@Marthandam Joint II;409~35@Mayiladurai Joint I;407~35@Mayiladuthurai Joint II;165~15@Mayilam;341~30@Mecheri;214~20@Meemisal;353~31@Meensurutti;373~32@Melakarur;540~46@Melaneelithanallur;500~43@Melapalayam;192~18@Melur;71~6@Mettupalayam;340~30@Mettur;311~28@Moganur;511~44@Moolakaraipatti;107~9@Moolanur;288~26@Morapur;250~23@Mudukolathur;466~40@Mukkoodal;486~42@Munchirai;501~43@Murapanadu;394~34@Musiri;417~36@Muthupettai;34~3@Mylapore;458~39@Nachiyarkovil;204~19@Nagalnaickenpatti;148~13@Nagalur;420~36@Nagapattinam Joint I;419~36@Nagoor;86~7@Nallur;175~16@Nallur_Vdm;313~28@Namagiripettai;314~28@Namakkal Joint I;308~28@Namakkal Joint II;116~10@Nambiyur;374~32@Nangavaram;512~44@Nanguneri;408~35@Nanilam;206~19@Natham;594~50@Natrampalli;278~25@Nayinar kovil;502~43@Nazareth;418~36@Needamangalam;16~1@Neelankarai;83~7@Negamam;124~11@Nellikuppam;558~47@nemili;205~19@Nilakkottai;596~50@Odugathur;337~30@Omalur;304~27@Oothangarai;49~5@Oothukkottai;91~8@Ooty Joint I;92~8@Ooty Joint II;437~37@Orathanadu;602~18@Othakadai;224~21@Ottanchatram;528~45@Ottapidaram;12~1@Padappai;290~26@Palacode;225~21@Palani Joint I;223~21@Palani Joint II;503~43@Palayankottai Joint I;84~7@Palladam;7~1@Pallavaram;597~50@Pallikonda;317~28@Pallipalayam;56~5@Pallipattu;477~41@Palliyadi;488~42@Palugal;15~1@Pammal;514~44@Panagudi;541~46@Panpozhi;125~11@Panruti;264~24@Panthalkudi;459~39@Papanasam;438~37@Pappanadu;291~26@Pappireddypatti;280~25@Paramakudi;315~28@Paramathi;153~14@Parangi pettai;289~26@Parur;436~37@Pattukottai Joint I;432~37@Pattukottai Joint II;542~46@Pavoorchatram;73~6@Peelamedu;179~16@Pennadam;292~26@Pennagaram;185~17@Peraiyur;411~35@Peralam;355~31@Perambalur;572~48@Peranamallur;440~37@Peravoorani;32~3@Periamet;239~22@Periyakulam Joint I;236~22@Periyakulam Joint II;69~6@Periyanayakkan Palayam;598~50@Pernampattu;57~5@Perumbakkam;253~23@Perunazhi;101~9@Perundurai;387~33@Perungalur;531~45@Perungulam;329~29@Pethanayakkanpalayam;515~44@Pettai;300~27@Pochampalli;254~23@Poghalur;85~7@Pollachi;585~49@Polur;216~20@Ponnamaravathi;25~2@Ponneri;8~1@Poonamallee;316~28@Puduchathiram;155~14@puduchattiram;530~45@Pudukottai;386~33@Pudukottai Joint I;126~11@Pudupettai;529~45@Pudur;543~46@Puliyangudi;356~31@Pullampadi;117~10@Punchaipuliyampatti;31~3@Purasaivakkam;516~44@Radhapuram;478~41@Rajackamangalam;265~24@Rajapalayam;251~23@Rajasinghamangalam;60~5@Ramakrishnarajupettai;256~23@Ramanathapuram Joint I;246~23@Ramanathapuram Joint II;252~23@Rameshvaram;318~28@Rasipuram;301~27@Rayakottai;26~2@Redhills;146~13@Rishivanthiyam;19~2@Royapuram;40~4@Salavakkam;324~29@Salem (East) Joint I;335~30@Salem West Joint I;336~30@Salem West Joint III;208~19@Sanarpatti;345~30@Sangagiri;544~46@Sankaranainarkoil;142~13@Sankarapuram;505~43@Sathankulam;113~10@Sathiyamangalam;160~15@Sathiyamangalam_tvm;266~24@Sathur;255~23@Sayalkudi;603~1@Selaiyur;21~2@Sembiam;357~31@Sendurai;209~19@Sendurai;547~46@Senkottah;319~28@Senthamangalam;152~14@Sethiyathope;267~24@Sethur;561~47@Sholingar;240~22@Sindupatti;217~20@Singampunari;67~6@Singanallur;412~35@Sirkazhi;176~16@Sirupakkam;279~25@Sivaganga Joint I;274~25@Sivaganga Joint II;97~9@Sivagiri_erode;545~46@Sivagiri_tenkasi;268~24@Sivakasi;302~27@Soolagiri;338~30@Sooramangalam;23~2@Sowcarpet;48~4@Sriperumpudur;396~34@Srirangam;506~43@Srivaikundam;269~24@Srivilliputhur;441~37@Subbramaniyapuram;80~7@Sulur;604~4@sunguvarchattram;104~9@Surampatti;546~46@Surandai;455~39@Swamimalai;6~1@T.Nagar;3~1@Tambaram;549~46@Tenkasi Joint I;537~46@Tenkasi Joint II;358~31@Tha.Pazhur;587~49@Thaanipadi;479~41@Thackalai;426~36@Thakkattur;331~29@Thalaivasal;114~10@Thalavadi;194~18@Thallakulam;53~5@Thamal;193~18@Thamaraipatti;330~29@Thammampatti;586~49@Thandarampattu;447~38@Thanjavur Joint I;375~32@Tharagampatti;339~30@Tharamangalam;413~35@Tharangampadi;397~34@Thathaiyangarpettai;573~48@Thellar;241~22@Theni;303~27@Thenkanikottai;195~18@Theppakulam;242~22@Thevaram;99~9@Thingalur;532~45@Thiruchendur;320~28@Thiruchengode;271~24@Thiruchuli;517~44@Thirukarungudi;451~38@Thirukattupalli;45~4@Thirukazhukundram;132~12@Thirukovilur;429~36@Thirukuvalai;187~17@Thirumangalam;388~33@Thirumayam;171~16@Thirumuttam;123~11@Thirunavalur;513~44@Thirunelveli Joint I;188~17@Thiruparakundram;422~36@Thirupoondi;457~39@Thiruppanandhal;218~20@Thiruppathur (Karaikudi);599~50@Thiruppathur (Vellore);46~4@Thirupporur;81~7@Thiruppur Joint I;82~7@Thiruppur Joint II;281~25@Thirupuvanam;270~24@Thiruthangal;423~36@Thiruthuraipoondi;54~5@Thiruttani;219~20@Thiruvadanai;452~38@Thiruvaiyaru;58~5@Thiruvalankadu;55~5@Thiruvallur;584~49@Thiruvannamalai Joint I;579~49@Thiruvannamalai Joint II;398~34@Thiruvarambur;424~36@Thiruvarur;489~42@Thiruvattar;131~12@Thiruvennainallur;456~39@Thiruvidaimaruthur;442~37@Thiruvonam;24~2@Thiruvottiyur;508~43@Thisaiyanvilai;170~16@Thittakudi;144~13@Thiyagadurgam;68~6@Thondamuthur;220~20@Thondi;115~10@Thookanaicken Palayam;87~7@Thottipalayam;481~41@Thovalai;173~16@Thozhuudhur;359~31@Thuraiyur;399~34@Thuvarankurichi;162~15@Tindivanam Joint I;163~15@Tindivanam Joint II;510~44@Tiurnelveli Joint II;395~34@Trichy Joint I;390~34@Trichy Joint III;30~3@Triplicane;524~45@Tuticorin - Melur;527~45@Tuticorin Joint I;520~45@Tuticorin Joint II;533~45@Udankudi;360~31@Udayarpalayam;76~7@Udumalapettai;444~37@Ullikottai;177~16@Ulundurpettai;361~31@Uppiliyapuram;400~34@Uraiyur;244~22@Usilampatti;243~22@Uthamapalayam;39~4@Uthiramerur;95~9@Uthukuli;548~46@Uthumalai;228~21@Vada madurai;145~13@Vadakkananthal;468~40@Vadakkuveeravanallur;127~11@Vadalur;147~13@Vadaponparappi;480~41@Vadaseri;74~6@Vadavalli;197~18@Vadipatti;460~39@Valankaiman;167~15@Valathi;136~12@Valavanur;362~31@Valighandapuram;453~38@Vallam;166~15@Vallam_tvm;518~44@Valliyur;574~48@Vandavasi;600~50@Vaniyampadi;168~15@Vanur;550~46@Vasudevanallur;210~19@Vathalakundu;272~24@Vathirairuppu;328~29@Vazhapadi;229~21@Veda senthur;428~36@Vedaranyam;282~24@Veerachozhan;333~29@Veerapandi;551~46@Veerasigamani;13~1@Velacheri;322~28@Velagoundampatti;377~32@Velayuthampalayam;108~9@Vellakovil;257~23@Vellipattinam;376~32@Velliyanai;595~50@Vellore Joint I;321~28@Velur;575~48@Vembakkam;305~27@Veppannapalli;365~31@Veppanthattai;178~16@Veppur;364~31@Veppur;490~42@Verkilambi;588~49@Vettavalam;469~40@Vickramasingapuram;138~12@Vikkravandi;363~31@Vikramangalam;534~45@Vilathikulam;36~3@Villivakkam;133~12@Villupuram Joint I;134~12@Villupuram Joint II;389~33@Viralimalai;263~24@Virudhunagar Joint I;260~24@Virudhunagar Joint II;9~1@Virugambakkam;169~16@Vriddhachalam Joint I;563~47@Walaja;61~5@Walajabad;334~29@Yercaud;";
 //alert(slistsro);
 var temp = slistsro.split(";");
 //alert(temp.length);

 if (id =="0") 
 {
 if (document.EC.Sro.options.length >= 1)
 document.EC.Sro.options.length = 1;
 //document.EC.Villagesel.value=""
 //document.EC.VillageName.value=""
 }
 //alert(temp);
 lCount = 1;
 checkid = 0; 
 for(i=0;i<temp.length-1;i++)
 {
       //alert(temp[i]);
  checkid = lCount;
  document.EC.Sro.options[lCount] = new 
Option(temp[i].substring(temp[i].indexOf("@")+1,temp[i].length),temp[i].substring(0,temp[i].indexOf("~")));    
//alert(temp[i].substring(temp[i].indexOf("@")+1,temp[i].length),temp[i].substring(0,temp[i].indexOf("~")));
lCount++;

if (id > 0)
 document.EC.Sro.selectedIndex = checkid;  
}
//removeFromList(document.getElementById("villagesel"))
}

function loadVillage(id)
{
 srocode = document.EC.Srosel.value;
 
}
function removeFromList(Robj) {
 var theDropDown = Robj
        var numberOfOptions = theDropDown.options.length  
         for (var i=0; i<numberOfOptions; i++) {  
          //Note: Always remove(0) and NOT remove(i)  
          theDropDown.remove(0)  
         }  
                               
         var target=Robj;
        var optionName = new Option('Select a Village', '');    
        var targetlength = target.length;    
        target.options[targetlength] = optionName; 
                               
                                                                       

}




</script> 
    
  



    <script>
  // You can also use "$(window).load(function() {"
  $(function () {
    // Slideshow 
    $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
   auto: true,
   pager: false,
   nav: true,
   speed: 500,
   namespace: "callbacks",
   before: function () {
     $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
   },
   after: function () {
     $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
   }
    });
  });
 </script>
```

like this...
For example, in the case `47~9@Arakkonam` it stores 47 in db. But I need to store as Arakkonam.

Please help me.

Comment: The javascript code looks incomplete? Can you add the remaining part?

Comment: added full javescript

Comment: Your script has wrong. 1. function names do not consist. 2.onchange do not need `javascript:`

Comment: I think you are using jquery. For jquery to try: `$( "#s_zoneoption:selected" ).text();`

Comment: could you give me more explanation...?

Comment: Hi are you from Cbe

Answer (score 0):

The `value` is what gets submitted with the post, so it is stored to the database.  Instead of specifying an integer, just use the text.  For example:
`<option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>`

Comment: If I use like this JavaScript not working. It runs with value numbers only.